# I am having trouble with eps file in Overleaf

Tags: overleaf, eps

I have a figure in eps-format that I want to have in my text, but it just comes up as blank square with this text:

```
Helikopterlab/Figurer/elevation_complexconjugated_1_i-eps-converted-to.pdf
```

I am using this code. I don't have issues with other images in other formats, only the eps-format.

```
\usepackage{epsfig}


\begin{figure}[htb]
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{Helikopterlab/Figurer/elevation_complexconjugated_1_i.eps}
  \caption{Helikopter}
  \label{Helikopter}
\end{figure}
```

Does anyone know what could cause this problem?

Comment: I changed the compilatior used in overleaf, and now it works!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.  If you put your answer into the answer box (and maybe include while compiler you changed to), then you'll be able to mark your answer as the one to solve your problem, and we'll be able to vote for (and against) it.

Comment: note that `epsfig` package was a legacy package when written in 1993 to support documents that were old then. there is no reason to use it in any document written this century.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I changed the compiler, used in Overleaf, from pdfLaTex to XeLaTex to be able to load the eps-files in to the document. I don't know why this worked, but it did!